# Can we use partial code from one html file to another html/php file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a solution to this but completely lost. Can anyone please help me get out of this situation?

I have created a menu using HTML code. I want to use that menu again and again into associated HTML files. Can I import/include that specific **part of HTML code** from that file **to another html/php** file?

```html
<select id="demo">
<option value="1">Option one</option>
<option value="2">Option Two</option>
<option value="3">Option Three</option>
</select>
```

Can I reuse this code again into other files?

Answer (score 1):

**in PHP you can use**

```
<body>
   <?php include "./header.html" ?>

   Content

   <?php include "./footer.html" ?>
</body>
```

**in HTML you can use**

```
<body>
   <include src="./header.html"></include>

   Content

   <include src="./footer.html"></include>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Permission to ask how can I import and use that specific menu to the other html file?

Comment: Put your menu HTML somewhere and use jQuery to load it into a designated element:

`$("#menu").load( "menu.html" );`